# is it possible to select a specific row index from a mysql select result set?

Tags: mysql

if I run a SELECT query that returns 10 rows, is there a way to select the 2nd item in the result set right in the SELECT statement (effectively getting a single row result)?

psedudo code:

SELECT id from MYTABLE where MYTABLE.foo = 0 and RESULT_INDEX = 2;

this would return the 2nd item from a multi item result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id from MYTABLE where MYTABLE.foo = 0 LIMIT 1, 1;
```

You'll probably want to specify an `ORDER BY` clause or else the *nth* result will be arbitrarily defined.

Edit: Oops, the first `LIMIT` param is zero based

Comment: I played with this, but it didn't produce the desired result, exactly.  If I limit 1 then I'll only get the first result, which isn't what I'm after.  I want the result set to be as many as it would organically be, but then to pluck the item from a specific location in that result set.  I'm doing it programmatic now, but was hoping there was a straight sql approach.

Comment: Did you use `LIMIT 1, 1`? This retrieves one record at offset 1 (second row) from the resultset. This sounds exactly like what you're after but I may be interpreting your question incorrectly.

Comment: no, I had followed your initial instructions, this works, thanks!